Confidence Level and Confidence Interval Question
So, I was scrolling around on Khan Academy, and I happened to notice this question:
“A researcher collecting information about $1000$ randomly selected physical therapists concluded that the median hourly wage for physical therapists in the United States at the the time of study was between $\$22.76$ and $\$59.24$, with a $95\%$ confidence level. Which of the following could represent the median hourly wage, based on the same sample, for physical therapists in the United States with a $90\%$ confidence level?”
A) $\$17.10$ to $\$64.90$
B) $\$20.48$ to $\$53.32$
C) $\$21.56$ to $\$56.12$
D) $\$25.65$ to $\$56.35$
Here’s a link to the question:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZVW3aVtE80
I was wondering whether a specific formula for calculating the confidence interval using a confidence level exists, as per the aforementioned question. I am provided with the confidence level $(95\%)$ and respective confidence interval ($22.76$ to $59.24$), and I am asked to determine the confidence interval for a confidence level of $90\%$. Is there a specific formula that can be applied to solve this (if the standard deviation and alternate values are not provided)?
I have just recently started statistics, so I don’t have extensive knowledge regarding this topic. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
This is kinda how I approached it:
$1.96/36.48 = 1.645/x$
^A ratio of Z score of $95\%$ to the range (confidence interval), set equivalent to the other Z score of $90\%$ to $x.$
$90\%$ corresponds to $1.645$, and $95\%$ to $1.96$ respectively
$x= 30.617$, so the answer is D. As $56.35-25.65 =30.7$
$30.7\approx 30.6$
Also, since the range (confidence interval) is less than that of the initial confidence interval and other confidence intervals, the confidence level would realistically be less.
That was my reasoning; people seem to be saying otherwise 
**For reference, some people seem to be saying that the answer is C, as apparently the interval of C is equal to
$34.56$, corresponding to a confidence level of $90\%$ as per their deduction.

Describe why you used your approach. Also state the problem in the question body itself instead of linking to the video.

I edited it; hope this helps.

I think its also important to note that one should use a distributional assumption (normality should be fine here).

Yep, I agree! But again, due to my limited knowledge of statistics, I was wondering if the answer I have obtained is even correct, and whether the method that I’ve used is even right.

Thanks for the formatting  @r.e.s.

Assuming the CIs are based on a normal approximation (which seems likely for the sample size of $1000$), any such interval has the form $$\hat m \pm (z_{1-\alpha\over2}\cdot s)$$
for a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ level of confidence, where $\hat m$ is a point-estimate of the population median, $s$ is a point-estimate of the standard deviation of $\hat m$, and $z_p$ denotes the $p$th standard normal quantile.
Consequently, for a given data-set, and under the above normality assumption,

the ratio you used, namely
$${\text{z-value}\over\text{width of CI}}={z_{1-\alpha\over2}\over2(z_{1-\alpha\over2}\cdot s) }={1\over2s}= \text{constant}$$
is constant for all $\alpha$. Thus, solving $${1.96\over 36.48}={1.645\over x}$$
does indeed give the width $x=30.62$, corresponding most closely to choice D (which has width $30.7$).

the midpoint of a CI is the same for all $\alpha$, and choice D is the only one whose midpoint ($41$) is equal to that of the given interval. (The same property implies the CIs are nested, and choice D is the only one that's a subinterval of the given interval.)



Thank you for your comment!

I would expect a $90\%$ confidence interval to be narrower than a $95\%$  confidence interval and, if constructed the same way, to be a subset of it.
A, B and C have lower points below that of the original $\$22.76$ so D seems the most plausible answer even before supposing a particular distribution. The video takes the same approach.
Since D also makes sense if you assume something like a normal distribution for the uncertainty centred at $41$ with a standard error of around $9.3$ (surprisingly large if the sample size really was $1000$) as suggested by the original interval, essentially reflecting your calculations and arguments, the desired answer is going to be D.

Thanks for your response!
